# INDEX or VLOOKUP to return rows with date matching TODAY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with with events/descriptions in 1 column and their corresponding date in another column. I'm looking for the correct function to get just the rows associated with todays date. The number of rows will grow over time so I am assuming this should be an ARRAY Formula. I've attached an image and a markdown table.

Hope that is all clear & thanks!

[googlesheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17YC_qZNLHqj_JA0okN7BxGzgoDeES0u_M9dz83aTx1M/edit?usp=sharing)

[events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXb1V.png)

| DATE | EVENT | DESCRIPTION |  | DATE | RESULT EVENT | RESULT DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tuesday, December 5, 2023 at 9:00:00 AM | MORNING MEETING | Follow up on data collection |  | 12/8/2023 | ON LOCATION | Steven Park Rehearsal |
| Tuesday, December 5, 2023 at 10:00:00 AM | REVIEW DECK | Notes needed for design team |  | 12/8/2023 | CLIENT REVIEW | Presentation for Shawmore Group |
| Tuesday, December 5, 2023 at 1:30:00 PM | DEEP WORK | Frienstuck Presentation |  |  |  |  |
| Wednesday, December 6, 2023 at 9:00:00 AM | ZOOM | Zoom with Juile,Cat,Billy |  |  |  |  |
| Wednesday, December 6, 2023 at 11:00:00 AM | MEETING | Josh - Get input on Calc development |  |  |  |  |
| Wednesday, December 6, 2023 at 1:00:00 PM | LUNCH | Meet Simra @ Jomba Cafe |  |  |  |  |
| Thursday, December 7, 2023 at 10:00:00 AM | ON LOCATION | Steven Park Rehearsal |  |  |  |  |
| Thursday, December 7, 2023 at 3:30:00 PM | CLIENT REVIEW | Presentation for Shawmore Group |  |  |  |  |
| Friday, December 8, 2023 at 9:00:00 AM | MORNING MEETING | Monthly Review |  |  |  |  |
| Friday, December 8, 2023 at 1:00:00 PM | LUNCH | Lunch with Tim and Paul |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter({to_date(A2:A),B2:C},int(A2:A)=today())
```

[image]

Comment: Bingo! This worked perfectly. Thanks so much